# Django. South. Can't migrate field: relation already exists

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I've been having lots of problems with South, I just can't add new fields.

So this is what I did:

- dropped the south_migrationhistory table from the database, deleted all the migration folders and uninstalled south "pip uninstall south".
- then, installed south again.
- ran syncdb to create the south table on the db.
- converted_to_south the app where I want to add the fields. (everything working fine till this point)
- ran schemamigration app --auto. And it gave me the regular message "+added field ... you can now apply this migration with .manage.py migrate app"
- did "python manage.py migrate app".

Get this error:

ProgrammingError: column "profile_image" of relation "profiles_profiles" already exists.
(the new fields I want to add are called "nickname" and "profile_image", the app name is called "profiles" and the model is called "profiles" as well).

I think I'm doing exactly what the docs write.

What I have tried:

- deleting everything and starting again a couple of times.
- faking a migration and then running "migrate" again. (I get "nothing to migrate", and then the same error "relation already exists")

Comment: You should paste the migration file generated. What DB are you using? If using say MySQL you could potentially have a partially migrated failure... and you'd need to drop the profile_image relation. You should inspect your database, and see if there indeed is a profile_image relation (is this a problem IN the migration, or outside?) etc.

Comment: Ok, so the database is PostgreSQL. I finally solved it in a ugly way: `psql -> ALTER TABLE profiles_profiles DROP COLUMN profile_image;` Then ran `python manage.py migrate profiles`. Not sure if this is ok and if there is a better way to do it.